# Ruby on rails, about looping

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I'm following a tutorial and there's a quiz I'm stuck at: http://prntscr.com/k35yx5

I've tried to approach it in many different ways but can't seem to find a solution. This is my final attempt before asking for help here: http://prntscr.com/k37bbl

Can you show me how its done? It's easier for me to understand if I can see the end result of this code.

Comment: It is always better to copy the piece of code which is difficult for your understanding. Remember, however, that Stackoverflow is not meant for training or babysitting third-party quizzes.

Comment: Post code, not screenshots of code

Answer (score 1):

That should work :)

```
puts 'You walk in greeted by grandma!'
puts 'She says "HI, SONNY!"'

while (reply = gets.chomp) != 'BYE'
  if reply == reply.upcase
    puts 'NO, NOT SINCE 19' + rand(19..51).to_s + '!' 
  else
    puts 'HUH?! SPEAK UP, SONNY!'
  end
end

puts 'BYE, SONNY'
```